# Multicollinearity with interaction term and fixed effects

Tags: r, multicollinearity

I have the following regression including an interaction term and fixed effects

```r
feols(work ~ i(age_cohort, log(tot_bomb_per)) + yrschool + nchild + 
    married + as.factor(minority) | geo1_vn1989 + age_cohort,
    subset(phc89, female == 1 & birthyr > 1925 & 
                    birthyr < 1974 & migration == 0),
    weights = ~ perwt, vcov = ~ geo1_vn1989)
```

`age_cohort` is the age cohort of individual i, `tot_bomb_per` is the province-level bombing intensity of province p, `geo1_vn1989` are province-level fixed effects and `age_cohort` are age cohort fixed effects.

After running that code, I am getting this message

```r
The variable 'age_cohort::61-65:log(tot_bomb_per)' has been removed
   because of collinearity (see $collin.var).
```

Can you please help me explain why I have encountered this error message, and if I should remove the fixed effects.